# Arabic charcters to English.. UTF-8 collation?

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, talend

Is it possible to change Arabic charcters to English by passing through a job in Talend???

We have some Arabic characters stored in our database and wish to change it to English characters by passing through Talend job.

We convert some *.csv files to SQL Database tables. 
Whenever, we convert .csv to SQL, the arab values changes to '?'.. ?????
We made sure to set the tables to UTF8 collation as well as the Talend job is processed through code UTF-8.

Does anyone has an idea about it??

Comment: Arabic to English? Can you show an example what this should look like?

Comment: Thanks for your reply...we have some arabic television channel names in *.csv file, eg: Dream 1 (1 الحلم )...which changes to 1????, when converted to SQL table. so, we would like to get either of 2 possibilites; either arab or translation to english ... looking forward to your reply..

Comment: make sure from the both the csv file are utf-8 and the databa is utf-8. check the csv to make sure not arabic-windows (cp1256) or not arabic-iso

Answer (score 0):

you can use this import command

```
SET character_set_database=utf8;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/tp/file.csv' REPLACE INTO TABLE sometable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"';
SET character_set_database=default;
```

Comment: where to exactly put it in Talend? We get *.csv in tfileoutputdelimited and then transfer it to tMysqlOutput .. so, where to exactly put it?